# Shared Desktop & Web based Javascript REST / Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, rest

I am running a node.js back-end with a Web based javascript client to send AJAX requests.

Now, I would like to do a small desktop version of the javascript client using pure Javascript, i.e. Google's V8.

In this scenario, how could I enable the AJAX support for the desktop version as there are no window / document objects ? In a perfect world in such a way that the Web and Desktop versions would share the same code ?

Or would I need to write the AJAX or REST API outside the js code, i.e. as native code and call it from js ?

Comment: All you need to do is make a simple HTTP request.

Comment: How ? As far as I know XMLHttpRequest is not supported by any of the current ECMAScript implementations.

Comment: It's not, and why should it be?  Making HTTP requests is part of the framework, not part of the language.  It sounds like you're building your own framework on top of V8.  I wouldn't do this... you could use something like Node.js (like you're already using on your server) which gives you plenty of framework to start with.  You summed it up in your last question... yes you will need to write this in native code and call that native code from your JS.  Or, use an existing framework.

Answer (score 0):

As Brad, says, there is currently no way to make an http request from the ECMAScript non-web implementations, even though there is a working draft at http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/ to integrate XMLHttpRequest to these implementations as well (I guess through external bindings).

What I did was to create a global function and implement it in the Web version like this:

```
function SendBackendRequest( url, parameters, func ) 
{ 
    var request=new ajaxRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if ( request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") ==-1 ) {

                func.call( this, request.responseText );
            } else {
                func.call( this, "" );
            }
        }
    }

    request.open( "POST", "http://localhost" + url, true );
    request.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    request.send( parameters );
};

ajaxRequest=function()
{
    var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];

    if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
        // --- IE
        for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++) {
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
            }

            catch(e) {
                //suppress error
            }
        }
    } else  
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // --- Mozilla, Safari etc
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        else return false;
    }
};
```

On the Desktop side I just implemented SendBackendRequest() as well and inside my client code can use the same code to communicate with the backend.